# postgresql: Need a sql query to find how many posts are there with one category

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, left-join

\d posts

```
                                   Table "public.posts"
   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying(100) | not null
 content     | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at  | date                   | 
 updated_at  | date                   | 
 tags        | character varying(55)  | not null default '50'::character varying
 category_id | integer                | not null default 1
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

\d categories

```
                                    Table "public.categories"
    Column     |         Type          |                        Modifiers                        
---------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer               | not null default nextval('categories_id_seq'::regclass)
 category_name | character varying(50) | not null
 created_at    | date                  | 
 updated_at    | date                  | 
Indexes:
    "categories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Need to count and get how many posts are there for one category. How can i do this?

Comment: It's not a mistake but does 'posts' table have foreign key to 'categories' table? (I can see only primary keys there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, c.category_name, COUNT(p.id)
   FROM public.categories c
       LEFT JOIN public.posts p
           ON c.id = p.category_id
   GROUP BY c.id, c.category_name
```

Comment: How can i ommit those rows with count = 0 ?

Comment: @guru: Change the `LEFT JOIN` to be an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT category_id, count(*) AS ct
FROM   posts
WHERE  category_id = $search_cat_id
GROUP  BY 1
```

Comment: No, I don't want to get it specifically with a category_id, rather i want to get all list of category with count.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT c.category_name, count(p.id) as NumberOfPosts
FROM public.posts p
LEFT JOIN public.categories c ON (p.category_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.category_name
```

To address the follow up question in the comment, you can filter the 0 counts using a nested query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT c.category_name, count(p.id) as NumberOfPosts
    FROM public.posts p
    LEFT JOIN public.categories c ON (p.category_id = c.id)
    GROUP BY c.category_name
) as countedPosts
WHERE countedPosts.NumberOfPosts > 0
```

Comment: How can i ommit those rows with count = 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

**For one category:**

```
select count(*) from posts where category_id=YOUCATEGORY;
```

**For all categories**

```
select c.category_name, count(*) from posts p, categories c where p.category_id = c.id group by c.id having count(*) != 0;
```

Comment: I need category_name with count .

Comment: Ready, also ommit rows with count 0

Comment: Your second query is wrong for group by, you need to add group by c.category_name too.

Comment: There is no need to group by category_name, because category_id is unique

Comment: @Jhonathan: Only true for PostgreSQL 9.1, and only for the **primary key** (not just unique). For older versions, you need to have all non-aggregated columns of the SELECT list in GROUP BY, too.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Ok, I agree.